# BQ scripting: Writing results of a loop to a table

Tags: google-bigquery

I am working with BigQuery scripting, I have written a simple WHILE loop which iterates through daily Google Analytics tables and sums the visits, now I'd like to write these results out to a table.

I've gotten as far as creating the table, but I can't capture the value of `visits` from my SQL query to populate the table. `Date` works fine, because it is defined outside of the SQL. I tried to `DECLARE` the value of `visits` with a new variable, but again this does not work because it's not known outside of the statement.

`SET vis = visits;`

How can I correctly write my results out to a table?

```
DECLARE d DATE DEFAULT DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
DECLARE pfix STRING DEFAULT REGEXP_REPLACE(CAST(d AS STRING),"-","");
DECLARE vis INT64;

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE test.looped_results (Date DATE, Visits INT64);

WHILE d > '2019-10-01' DO
  SELECT d, SUM(totals.visits) AS visits
  FROM `project.dataset.ga_sessions_*`
  WHERE _table_suffix = pfix
  GROUP  BY Date;
  SET d = DATE_SUB(d, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
  SET vis = visits;
  INSERT INTO test.looped_results VALUES (d, visits);
END WHILE;
```

**Update**: I also tried an alternative solution, assigning visits to it's own variable, but this produces the same error:

```
WHILE d > '2019-10-01' DO
  SET vis_count = (SELECT SUM(totals.visits) AS visits
                    FROM `mindful-agency-136314.43786551.ga_sessions_*`
                    WHERE _table_suffix = pfix);

  INSERT INTO test.looped_results VALUES (d, vis_count);

  SET d = DATE_SUB(d, INTERVAL 1 DAY);

END WHILE;
```

Results:

[image]

In my results I see the correct number of rows created, with the correct dates, but the value of `visits` for each is the value for the most recent day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you need to update the `pfix` variable in there. Also, it is a good idea to instantiate the `visits`. Finally, your `GROUPBY` doesn't necessarily need a dimension if you are providing it with a `pfix` constraint.

This should do it:

```
DECLARE d DATE DEFAULT DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
DECLARE pfix STRING DEFAULT REGEXP_REPLACE(CAST(d AS STRING),'-','');
DECLARE visits int64;
SET visits = 0;

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE project.dataset.looped_results (Date DATE, Visits INT64);

WHILE d > '2019-10-01' DO
  SET visits = (SELECT SUM(totals.visits) FROM `project.dataset.ga_sessions_*` WHERE _table_suffix = pfix);
  SET d = DATE_SUB(d, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
  SET pfix = REGEXP_REPLACE(CAST(d AS STRING),"-","");
  INSERT INTO dataset.looped_results VALUES (d, visits);
END WHILE;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @khan spot on! The only change being that I moved the `INSERT` above the `SET` for the new variables, so I can insert them into the table before I make the changes for the next loop. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I would also move `INSERT INTO` outside of the `WHILE` loop by collecting result into `result` variable (along with few other minor changes) as in below example

```
DECLARE d DATE DEFAULT DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
DECLARE pfix STRING; 
DECLARE vis_count INT64;
DECLARE result ARRAY<STRUCT<vis_date DATE, vis_count INT64>> DEFAULT [];

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE test.looped_results (Date DATE, Visits INT64);

WHILE d > '2019-10-01' DO
  SET pfix = REGEXP_REPLACE(CAST(d AS STRING),"-","");
  SET vis_count = (SELECT SUM(totals.visits) AS visits
                    FROM `project.dataset.ga_sessions_*`
                    WHERE _table_suffix = pfix);
  SET result = ARRAY_CONCAT(result, [STRUCT(d, vis_count)]);
  SET d = DATE_SUB(d, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
END WHILE;

INSERT INTO test.looped_results SELECT * FROM UNNEST(result);
```

Note: I hope your example is for scripting learning purpose and not for production as whenever possible we should stick with set based processing which can be easily done in your case

Comment: Thanks @Mikhail - can you explain what you mean by "set based processing"?

Comment: check [Understanding “Set based” and “Procedural” approaches in SQL](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34142/Understanding-Set-based-and-Procedural-approaches). you can google for more :o)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a better way which is faster and without using a loop.

Basically, you form an array of suffix and do SELECT/INSERT in single query:

```sql
DECLARE date_range ARRAY<DATE> DEFAULT
  GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(DATE '2019-10-01', DATE '2019-10-10', INTERVAL 1 DAY);

DECLARE suffix_array ARRAY<STRING> 
  DEFAULT (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(REGEXP_REPLACE(CAST(dates AS STRING),"-","")) 
           FROM UNNEST(date_range) dates);

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE test.looped_results (Date DATE, Visits INT64);

INSERT INTO test.looped_results
SELECT Date, SUM(totals.visits)
FROM `project.dataset.ga_sessions_*`
WHERE _table_suffix in UNNEST(suffix_array);
GROUP BY Date;
```

Answer (score 1):

Having reviewed my code (several times!) I realized that I wasn't refreshing the variable which transforms the data into the table prefix within the loop.

Here is a working version of the script, where I set `pfix` at the end of the loop:

```
DECLARE d DATE DEFAULT DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
DECLARE pfix STRING DEFAULT REGEXP_REPLACE(CAST(d AS STRING),"-","");
DECLARE vis_count INT64;
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE test.looped_results (Date DATE, Visits INT64);

WHILE d > '2019-10-01' DO
  SET vis_count = (SELECT SUM(totals.visits) AS visits
                    FROM `project.dataset.ga_sessions_*`
                    WHERE _table_suffix = pfix);
  INSERT INTO test.looped_results VALUES (d, vis_count);
  SET d = DATE_SUB(d, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
  SET pfix = REGEXP_REPLACE(CAST(d AS STRING),"-","");
END WHILE;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would actually not use a while loop but rather a group by

```
SELECT date, SUM(totals.visits) AS visits
FROM `mindful-agency-136314.43786551.ga_sessions_*`
GROUP BY Date;
```

It will give you your results as the table that you want, you don't need to loop on your table.
Depending on your set up but you can set the query to be ran every day so every new day you will have the new values